# QoS on GPRS connection

Tags: qos, gprs

I have a question about QoS (Quality of Service) on GPRS connection. I have linux server with many connected clients through GPRS. Each of them communicates at the same time via ftp, http etc. How can I divide communication (for example ftp will get 10 % of bandwidth, communication via http will get 30 % and other 60 %)?
I tried tc (traffic control tool) and qdisc like htb, cbq and other. There is a problem because htb and cbq algorithms require to know the baud rate. But I don't know it, because GPRS connection is very unstable (8 kb/s - very good signal to 100 b/s - bad signal). Clients are moving.
I also tried the prio qdisc, but it doesn't work. Because the ethernet on server is much faster than GPRS and do not form a queue so the prio didn't work (bottleneck is at the GSM operator's gw).
 Do you have any idea how to set QoS on server?

Comment: I see what you want to do, but I'm not sure how it would work.  How is a server to reserve 10% of a bandwidth *that is unknown and variable* for (say) FTP?  You can probably codify that the *first* (say) 100kB/s will go to FTP, then the *next* 300kB/s (when available) will go to HTTP, then any bandwidth after that will be equally shared.  Would that do?

Comment: Thank you, but bandwidth is highly variable as you say. I want to set only the ratio between connections. I do not know if it's possible.

Comment: I suspect it is unlikely, because **the server won't know what number to calculate 10% of** when deciding how many FTP packets to emit from the QOS'ed interface.  Seriously: imagine you're the server.  What total volume of FTP packets should you send out the GPRS-facing interface this second, in order to have consumed 10% of the usable bandwidth?  How could you possibly answer that question?

Comment: I did not realize it. Yes you're right. Do you have any idea how to prioritize connections, when i don't the bandwith.

Comment: As I suggested above; would that do?